# Wordpress the_content - Shortcodes Not Working Inside WooCommerce Filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, shortcode

I am bashing my head against a wall here.

I have a filter as follows for woocommerce to attach files to emails it sends:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_email_attachments","__fuelprot_attach",10,3);
```

The filter fires, and the files are attached just fine. However, the file i am attaching is a PDF generated from a wordpress page. The page has a tablepress shortcode in it.

So within the woocommerce filter the output is parsed through the_content filter as follows:

```
echo apply_filters("the_content",$facts[0]->post_content);
```

The tablepress shortcode is not working here, but works fine when viewing the actual page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) inside the filter?

Comment: i did indeed. i went for a different option rather than messing about trying to figure out why that wasn't working. I have a feeling it was due to the shortcode not existing by the time the filter is called